# How overwrite the copy handler of the windows explorer without UAC

Tags: winapi, regsvr32

I have see Teracopy and CopyHandler, intercept the copy by overwrite copy handler.
But in my case, that's wakeup the UAC.

The code used: https://github.com/alphaonex86/Ultracopier/blob/master/plugins/PluginLoader/catchcopy-v0002/pluginLoader.cpp
into PluginLoader::RegisterShellExtDll()

The other seam have the same. Mainly I use regsvr32 my_dll.dll to load into the explorer.
Some body have tip to not open the UAC?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course not, you cannot install shell extension handlers without letting the user know that you are messing with her machine.

Comment: Some software do that's (overwrite ctrl-c cltr-v), I have see about manifest problem (active the UAC), but I have failed.